# Disable parent link in dropdown navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation, something like the following...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="page.html" id="hyperlink1">Link</a>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
             <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
             <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Id like to disable the parent link with the id 'hyperlink1'.

Ive tried doing this in jQuery with the following

```
$("a#HyperLink1").click(function() { return false; });
```

only it seems to disable all the child links too, has anybody a better solution?

Comment: IDs are case-sensitive, `#HyperLink1` != `$hyperlink1`. Show your real, relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prevent the default behaviour of the anchor... by using the [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method on the Event object. :)...

```
$("a#HyperLink1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This allows the event to bubble through the DOM; which ensure's any other handlers you've got listening for the event to fire, but it prevents the default behaviour being executed (e.g. prevents a link opening for an anchor, prevents a form submission on a `submit` button).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the href attribute (if it's not a link, it shouldn't be a link):

```
$('#hyperlink1').removeAttr('href');
```

And also ID's are case-sensitive.